# Phpstorm 8.0.1 out-of-memory

Tags: java, phpstorm

I have problem in phpstorm,it suddenly show this box.

[image: Out of Memory]

I'm using OS windows 8 32bit.I don't know how can I fix this everytime I open my project this will launch immediately.

**Answer**

I increase the xmx settings to 1000m.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: just as it says, increase Xmx size

Comment: I think that is not the good solution

Comment: In the install directory for PhpStorm, in the bin/ folder, there's a Phpstorm.exe.vmoptions file. You can edit that and change the default Xmx value (at 32-bit, you'll be pretty limited to what you can set)

Answer (score 0):

for understand this properties of Java JVM which use by PHPStorm to run on OS you can view this doc : [JVM options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html)

Whereas it's a great idea to migrate on 64bits system of possible.